# Potential causes for a php session unset after calling header function?

Tags: php, session

I am setting 2 session variables and then called the header function.

(SecurityCheck.php)

```
$_SESSION['danger'] = "true";
$_SESSION['priviledgeError'] = "You do not have access";
header('Location: index.php');
```

However, when the header re-directs to the proper page, only one of the sessions retains its value, even though I never called any type of session unset method.

(index.php)

```
echo 'line 63 index.php';
echo "<br>danger session is: " . isset($_SESSION['danger']);
echo "<br>priviledge session is: " . isset($_SESSION['priviledgeError']);

line 63 index.php
danger session is: 
priviledge session is: 1
```

I have checked through all relevant files for any places I may have called an unset function, and made sure session_start() is appended to the top of both pages.

I expect that both sessions will return "1" and not just one of them.

Entire Index.php file:

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">

    <style>

        #userPass
        {
            padding; 20px;
        }

        #logIn
        {
            padding: 20px;
            position:relative;
            border-style: solid;
            margin:auto;
            background-color: white;
            width: 390px;
            height: 160px;
        }

        #log-in-header
        {
            position: absolute;
            left:46%;
            font-size: 35px;
            color:black;
        }

        #submitButton
        {
            position: relative; 
            top: 83px;
            width: 347px;
        }

        td
        {
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<!--ONLY runs when user has clicked LOG-IN-->

<body>




<div id='container'>
    <?php
            echo 'line 63 index.php';
            echo "<br>danger session is: " . isset($_SESSION['danger']);
            echo "<br>priviledge session is: " . 
isset($_SESSION['priviledgeError']);
            // die;
        require 'header.php';
        require 'messages.php';
    ?>

    <br>
    <p id='log-in-header'>
        Log-In
    </p>
    <hr><br><br><br>

        <form method="post" action="login.php">
            <div id='logIn'>
<!--                    <div id='userPass'>-->
                        <table style = "position: relative; bottom: 
40px;">

                            <tr>
                                <td style='font-size: 20px'>Username:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" style='color: 
black' name="userName" id='user' ></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td style='font-size: 20px'>Password:</td>
                                <td><input type="password" style='color: 
black' name="password" id='pass' ></td>
                            </tr?

                        </table>
<!--                   </div>-->

                   <div id='submitButton'>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
style='color: black; font-size: 20px' value="Log In">           
                   </div>     
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
<!-- LOG-IN form ENDS -->


    <!--  JS scrips-->

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>-->

</body>
</html>`
```

UPDATE: added a new session entry, as well as a session deleteion to SecurityCheck.php

```
$_SESSION['danger'] = "true";
$_SESSION['priviledgeError'] = "You do not have access 
unset($_SESSION['priviledgeError']);
$_SESSION['newSession'] = "hi";
header('Location: index.php');
```

Here is code in index.php:

```
echo 'line 63 index.php';
echo "<br>danger session is: " . isset($_SESSION['danger']);
echo "<br>priviledge session is: " . 
isset($_SESSION['priviledgeError']);
echo "<br>new session is: " . $_SESSION['newSession'];
```

Here is result:

```
line 63 index.php
danger session is: 
priviledge session is: 
new session is: hi
```

Comment: Ok, I added the complete index.php file. Nothing else is relevent since the session is definetely being unset after the header executes.

Comment: Ok, this is the result. "array(5) { ["userName"]=> string(5) "Admin" ["logged_in"]=> bool(true) ["page"]=> string(9) "wlManager" ["role"]=> string(5) "admin" ["priviledgeError"]=> string(98)"

Comment: what do you mean by "please try the first one after session reset"?

Comment: Result of placing exit(var_dump($_SESSION)); before header('Location: index.php');                                                                                                   array(6) { ["userName"]=> string(5) "Admin" ["logged_in"]=> bool(true) ["page"]=> string(9) "wlManager" ["role"]=> string(5) "admin" ["priviledgeError"]=> string(98) "You do not have access to case manager priviledges, if you are a case manager please sign in here." ["danger"]=> string(4) "true" }

Comment: reset all the sessions? Where should I do it? Line 1 of index(the starting point of my web app)?

Comment: Yes. I have used these sessions in a different way so I know it works, just not with a certain variable.

Comment: Ok, I reset all sessions, ran it again and still prividgeerror returns 1 and danger returns nothing.

Comment: Ok, I just listed changes made to the OP.

Comment: i'm going to delete my previous comments and i will be still looking. good luck